# How to get stacked barh-plot using column of pandas dataframe to stack the bars?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have two dataframes:

The first dataframe `df1`:

```
Name Group
Abc A
Bcd A
Cde B
Def C
```

The second dataframe `df2`:

```
Name Group
Efg A
Fgh B
Ghi C
Hij C
```

**First Step**

What I did was to create a new dataframe df_new which contains `Group` as a column and length of `df1` and `df2` as another column:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['1', '2'],
    'length': map(len, [df1, df2])
})
```

**Second Step**

And then used the following code to plot `df_new` as `barh`-plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
df_new.plot.barh(width=0.75,ax=ax,figsize=(12,8))
ax.set_title('Title')
ax.set_xlabel('Number')
ax.set_ylabel('Group')
ax.set_xlim([0,20])
for i, v in enumerate(df_new['Anzahl']):
    ax.text(x = v + 1, y = i + .1, s = str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
plt.savefig(os.path.join('test.png'), dpi=400, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

This works out but instead of getting a normal barh-plot with one continuous bar for each dataframe I want to get a `barh`-plot stacked by the `Group`-column from my original dataframes `df1` and `df2`. What do I have to do differently in the first step where I create `df_new` and what in the second step where I plot `df_new`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a group for each dataframe using the column `Group`, then, use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) `count` to count the number of rows with the same `Group` type on each group, change the column name (this will ease the process for data plot) and put them inside a list. After, use `pd.concat` to concatenate both dataframes along the column axis (`axis=1`), this will place the data in the desired format for the `barh`. What remains now to obtain the barh-plot stacked by Group-columns is to set the `stacked` parameter for the bar plot (`stacked=True`).

```py
df_list = []
for idx, df in enumerate([df1, df2], 1):
    df_agg = df.groupby('Group').agg('count')
    df_agg.columns = [f'Dataframe-{idx}']
    df_list.append(df_agg)

dff = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dff.plot.barh(width=0.75,ax=ax,figsize=(12,8), stacked=True)
ax.set_title('Title')
ax.set_xlabel('Number')
ax.set_ylabel('Group')
ax.set_xlim([0,dff.max().max()*2])
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot_stacked_groups]